# Update custom fields on Paypal

Tags: node.js, paypal

I use the NVP integration on Paypal and I'm facing a situation that I need to create a method to update some info on an already placed Paypal order. The only field that I need to update (edit) is PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CUSTOM, but looking on the docs I couldn't find any put/patch methods that would help me here.

Anyone has any inputs on this case? Have anyone ever update info on placed orders on Paypal?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is no method to patch the information of an already completed PayPal sale transaction.  Once such a transaction has completed, it is final.

---

If using paymentaction=order or paymentaction=authorization, you can update information when doing the DoCapture which is the final step to create a transaction. This final step can fail, so do not change your integration to paymentaction=order or paymentaction=authorization unless you have very specific business needs for those features.